# Meaning of return HttpResponse("")

Tags: python, django

In python, what the meaning of the below code if written in a function

```
return HttpResponse("")
```

Comment: Which word is confusing?

Answer (score 5):

All [Django views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/views/) must return an HTTP response.

`HttpResponse("")` is the simplest way to return a response in Django. It doesn't have any content, since `""` is an empty string).

It's not a very useful line of code, most of the time you would only use temporarily it to get your view working, then replace it with something more useful. It could be used if you wanted to set up automated monitoring to check that your Django website is running.